# Failed to transfer file with status code 409 maven

Tags: java, maven

So I have multi module project made in java. And in one of the modules I had to add new dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.donkey.great</groudId>
    <artifactId>DonkeyRoll</artifactId>
    <version>LATEST-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

But when importing libs I am getting error:

```
Failure to transfer com.donkey.great:DonkeyRoll:LATEST-SNAPSHOT
from https://artifactory.of.greatest.donkey.ever.com/artifactory/libs-release
was cached in the local repostiroy, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval
of artifactory.of.greatest.donkey.ever.com/artifactory/libs-release has elapsed or update are forced. 
Original error: Could not transfer artifact com.donkey.great:DonkeyRoll:LATEST-SNAPSHOT:
Failed to transfer file https://artifactory.of.greatest.donkey.ever.com/artifactory/libs-release/com/donkey/great/DonkeyRoll/LATEST-SNAPSHOT with status code 409
```

I read that `mvn clean install -u` could help but not in this case.
I observed that this package is already downloaded with specific version, because some of internals jars in other modules are importing it.

Anyone has idea what could go wrong? :)

Comment: Remove `LATEST-` and replace it with the correct version...

Comment: @khmarbaise at this moment I need to use `LATEST-`, but event after changing it to the specific version I am getting the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this to your pom.xml, and I think it should work for you.

```xml
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>oss.sonatype.org-snapshot</id>
    <url>http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
    <releases>
      <enabled>false</enabled>
    </releases>
    <snapshots>
      <enabled>true</enabled>
    </snapshots>
  </repository>
</repositories>
```

You can also add below to your settings.xml to make it work.

```xml
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>allow-snapshots</id>
    <activation><activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault></activation>
    <repositories>
      <repository>
        <id>snapshots-repo</id>
        <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
        <releases><enabled>false</enabled></releases>
        <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
      </repository>
    </repositories>
  </profile>
</profiles>
```